# php IntlDateFormatter doesn't work as expected

Tags: php, symfony

the code is quite simple, I want to transform a string in to DateTime object using IntlDateFormatter, however the result is completely different from the original one. What I did wrong? the following code is constructed based on `DateTimeToLocalizedStringTransformer` of `Symfony4.3`

```
<?php

//turn string to timestamp
$t = new \IntlDateFormatter('en_US', 2, 2, new DateTimeZone('Asia/Shanghai') , 1, 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
$t->setLenient(false);
$timestamp = $t->parse('2019-09-18 18:58:08');

//turn timestamp back to string
$date = new DateTime();
$date->setTimestamp($timestamp);
$date->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone('Asia/Shanghai'));

echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\n"; //output : 2019-01-18 18:09:00, why?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, lets get rid of magic numbers and circumstantial checks, just to be sure:

```
$t = new \IntlDateFormatter(
    'en_US',
    IntlDateFormatter::MEDIUM,
    IntlDateFormatter::MEDIUM,
    new DateTimeZone('Asia/Shanghai'),
    IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN,
    'Y-m-d H:i:s');
$t->setLenient(false);
$timestamp = $t->parse('2019-09-18 18:58:08');
var_dump(date('r', $timestamp));
```

This [prints](https://3v4l.org/OPdu1) `Fri, 18 Jan 2019 11:09:00 +0100`. So, what's the deal?

The problem is the last [constructor parameter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intldateformatter.create.php#refsect1-intldateformatter.create-parameters). You're taking for granted that format codes are the same as in e.g. `date()` but that's not what docs say:

> Optional pattern to use when formatting or parsing. Possible patterns are documented at » http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime.

- `Y` means *year of "Week of Year"*.
- `m` means *minute in hour*.

... and so on.

Comment: var_dump (date ('r', $ timestamp)); returns the time with the default time zone of the server. For a correct time, you must first set a date_default_timezone_set ('Asia / Shanghai');.

Comment: @jspit That's right. This was just a quick diagnostic to double-check the main issue (totally wrong month, minutes and seconds) which was clearly not a simple time zone problem. There's no confusion though since it prints the time zone anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The date formats for IntlDateFormatter are wrong, you need the [ICU formats](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime).

It is also better to use constants instead of integers.

```
$dateStr = '2019-09-18 18:58:08';
$t = new \IntlDateFormatter('en_US', IntlDateFormatter::FULL, IntlDateFormatter::FULL, 'Asia/Shanghai' ,IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'); 
$t->setLenient(false);
$timestamp = $t->parse($dateStr);

//turn timestamp back to string
$dateStrFromTs = date_create(null,new \DateTimeZone('Asia/Shanghai'))
  ->setTimestamp($timestamp)
  ->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')
;

var_dump($dateStrFromTs === $dateStr);  //bool(true)
```